# Onclicklistener on customview not working

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I have a customview:

```
public class GalleryView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CallBackHandler callBackHandler;
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();

    public GalleryView(Context context, CallBackHandler callBackHandler) {
        super(context);
        this.callBackHandler = callBackHandler;
    }

    public GalleryView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawPaint(myPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("clicked !");
        callBackHandler.do();
    }
}
```

I am adding this to my linearLayout of my main activity:

```
linearLayout.addView(galleryView);
```

And I set that layout to my contantview:

```
setContentView(linearLayout);
```

I can see the view red, but clicking is not triggered.

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simply setting OnClickListener as below:

```
public class GalleryView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    private CallBackHandler callBackHandler;

    public GalleryView(Context context, CallBackHandler callBackHandler) {
        this(context, null, callBackHandler);
    }

    public GalleryView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, CallBackHandler callbackHandler) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        this.callBackHandler = callbackHandler;
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawPaint(myPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("clicked !");
        callBackHandler.do();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line inside on create :

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Basically, when you add this line You assign `OnClickListener` to your view using `setOnClickListener(this)` and that's how inside `onClick`, the onClick of the assigned `OnClickListener` is called.